# How to make existing classes to be a class template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

For example, I have several existing point classes for 2D (two-dimensional) and 3D cases, like `class Point2D` and `class Point3D`. And I want it to be templated like `template<int D> class Point` where `Point<2>` is equivalent or directly use `Point2D` and `Point<3>` is equivalent or directly use `Point3D`. I don't want to reimplement those existing classes since my real classes are not as simple as class point and it is third-party code, like

```
using Point<2> = Point2D;
using Point<3> = Point3D;
```

Any way to do it?

Comment: You're not re-implementing, you're refactoring. Your template class becomes the base and provides some generic methods for PointND, and the derived classes can add specializations

Comment: You should post code.

Comment: I'd say it entirely depends on what those two classes currently look like.

Comment: should be moved to code review with the code of the actual classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use template specialization:

```
template <int> struct PointImpl;
template <> struct PointImpl<2> { using Type = Point2D; };
// ...

template <int D> using Point = typename PointImpl<D>::Type;
```

Answer (score 8):

Of course! Don't modify the classes, add a typedef instead:

```
template <int D>
struct pointType_;

template <>
struct pointType_<2> { using type = Point2D; };

template <>
struct pointType_<3> { using type = Point3D; };

template <int D>
using Point = typename pointType_<D>::type;
```